# react tabular - get current row data in cell transform

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following column definition:

```
{
    property: 'referenceNumber',
        header: {
    label: strings.referenceNumber
},
    cell: {
        transforms: [
            value => ({
                onClick: () => alert(`${value}`)
            })
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I would like to alert another value from the row (stored under ID). This is an example of my row definition:

```
{
  referenceNumber:"20170410-6c3a06cf-b6f8-4e44-b157-be9e7307605a06"
  status:"WAITING"
  id: '1'
}
```

According to the [react tabular docs](https://reactabular.js.org/#/column-definition/cell) this should be possible, but the following code is not working (rowData is undefined):

```
transforms: [
              value => ({
                  onClick: () => alert(`${rowData}`)
              })
            ]
```

I am stuck trying to access the rowdata property.

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of transforms on the docs you have to use

```
cell.transforms = [(<value>, { columnIndex: <number>, column: <object>, rowData: <object>, rowIndex: <number>, property: <string> }) => ({... props ...})]
```

I don't see you passing `rawData`

Comment: I tried doing rowData => console.log(rowData) but this will just return the value of the current cell instead of the object with the values for the whole row. This is my basic question - how do I pass rowData to the transforms function

Comment: if I didn't miss something, the `rowdata` is passed as second parameter `(value, {rowData: rowData}) => console.log(rowData)

Comment: This just returns undefined. I've written a workaround using MobX store, but would like to get to the bottom of this in any case